# Why the values are not being inserted in the database?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

My database code looks like this.

```
        public void addprofileinfo(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("StudentName", queryValues.get("StudentName"));
        values.put("RegistrationNo", queryValues.get("RegistrationNo"));
        values.put("Faculty", queryValues.get("Faculty"));
        values.put("TotalFeePaid", queryValues.get("TotalFeePaid"));

        database.insert("FEE", null, values);

        database.close();
```

And Activity Code is:
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.insertfield);
        editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editFaculty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextfaculty);
        editFee=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTexttotalfeepaid);
        editRegid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextid);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsave);

```
addData();
}

public void addData(){
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{

                HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            queryValuesMap.put("StudentName",editName.getText().toString());
            queryValuesMap.put("Faculty", editFaculty.getText().toString());
            queryValuesMap.put("TotalFee",      editFee.getText().toString());
            queryValuesMap.put("RegistrationNo",        editRegid.getText().toString());

            dbtools.addprofileinfo(queryValuesMap);
            Toast.makeText(insertData.this, "Successful!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            dbtools.close();
            insertData.this.finish();



            }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(insertData.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }}
            });
```

Successful saved message appears but the value is not found into database. Please tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put:

```
        dbtools.close();
        insertData.this.finish();
```

Before:

```
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I did it but vote up  is not being displayed. i think due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        dbtools.close();
        insertData.this.finish();
```

This works..

Answer (score 0):

but it is more better to use

```
    dbtools.close();
    insertData.this.finish(); 
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

i.e close your database and start the ativity

Comment: Both of your answer are satisfactory,  but I suggest you to include all the possibilities in one single answer so that users will find all sorts of answers in a single one. This will certainly make a great difference.